# Some snap application menus don't display properly in 20.04.2 LTS with MATE 1.24.0

Tags: 20.04, mate, menu

Some menus do not display properly in 20.04 with MATE 1.24.0 (example below) - even within the same program some display properly others don't - is not affected by whether the app displays in dark mode like system default or does its own default color - it's not affected by changing the theme either - I think it appeared with an update to 20.04 LTS but I am not 100% sure as it only happens in some menus in some apps - any ideas how to fix this? Is this a known issue?

[image: example of the weirdly scrambled menu]

[image: example of not scrambled menu in the same app]

Comment: What is OpenComic? How it was installed? It maybe Snap theming issue. Please give more examples about "some menus in some apps". Which video adapter do you use? Is it real hardware or virtual machine?

Comment: I know that 'Zoom' does it too...

Using AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 11 Graphics (RAVEN, DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-77-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)

Comment: and yes open Comics (simple cbr/cbz viewer) was in fact installed through snap - so was zoom

Comment: It smells like a snap theming issue - I think you are right @N0rbert

Comment: Another thread to read is https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/20-04-display-issues-with-amd-gpu/21648 . But it seems that you do not have issues with normal deb-packaged applications, right? I would also suggest to create new topic there about your OpenComic problem to move it forward.

Comment: Yes I can 100% confirm - found another app that does it (Skype) - could confirm: deb-package=no issue - snap-version=scramble menus all over the place

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Skype on Ubuntu 20.04:

[image: same issue with Skype]

The problem was solved (accidentally) by disabling the *opengl: allows access to OpenGl stack* permission for Skype in the Ubuntu Settings.

[image: Skype permissions in Ubuntu Settings]

The result is below:

[image: result]